# Let $U$, $V$ be $F$-vector spaces with infinite dimensions $\kappa$ and $\lambda$. What's the dimension of the space $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$?

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let $U$, $V$ be $F$-vector spaces with infinite dimensions $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ (which are cardinals), respectively. What's the dimension of the space of all linear maps between $U$ and $V$, i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$?

My process is as follows:

First, calculate the cardinality of $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$. Let $K$ be the base of $U$. We can see that every linear map between $U$ and $V$ is uniquely determined by its values on $K$, so that
$$|\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)| = |V^K| = \max\{\lambda, |F|\}^\kappa.$$ (I use the equation $|V|=\max\{|B|,|F|\}$ when $V$ is an infinite space.)
Let $B$ be the base of $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$. Apply the equation again we have
$$|\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)| = \max\{\lambda, |F|\}^\kappa = \max\{|B|,|F|\}.$$
Since $\max\{\lambda, |F|\}^\kappa>|F|$ I arrive at the result $|B| = \max\{\lambda, |F|\}^\kappa$.